# R - leaflet - highcharter tooltip

Tags: r, highcharts, leaflet, r-leaflet, r-highcharter

I want to include a `highcharter` plot in my `leaflet` popup. With help from [this](http://bl.ocks.org/timelyportfolio/33db1fb9e64257ef7149754bdff0b2e0) post Iam able to include a `sparkline` plot. However, due to my lack of html skills I dont know how to modify the code to work with `highcharter`. [This answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35808723/adding-a-highchart-to-a-leaflet-popup) ([example from answer](http://plnkr.co/edit/J2ByvguqO56oe1cE6J0j?p=preview)) is exactly what I want. I just dont know how to implement in in `R`.

```
library(leaflet)
library(tidyverse)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(htmltools)
library(sparkline)
library(highcharter)

# Step 1 convert htmlwidget to character representation of HTML components
as.character.htmlwidget <- function(x, ...) {
  htmltools::HTML(
    htmltools:::as.character.shiny.tag.list(
      htmlwidgets:::as.tags.htmlwidget(
        x
      ),
      ...
    )
  )
}


add_deps <- function(dtbl, name, pkg = name) {
  tagList(
    dtbl,
    htmlwidgets::getDependency(name, pkg)
  )
}
```

This works fine:

```
leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addCircleMarkers(lat = 45.4, lng = 14.9,
                   popup = list(paste(as.character(sparkline(1:19))))) %>%
  onRender(
    "
function(el,x) {
  this.on('popupopen', function() {HTMLWidgets.staticRender();})
}
") %>%
  add_deps("sparkline") %>%
  browsable()
```

[image]

Unfortunately its not just change `add_deps` to `highcharter`

```
leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addCircleMarkers(lat = 45.4, lng = 14.9,
                   popup = list(paste(as.character(
                     hchart(data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10), type = "line", hcaes(x = x, y = y)) %>% hc_size(width = 300, height = 200)
                     ))),
                   popupOptions = popupOptions(minWidth = 300, maxHeight = 200)) %>%
  onRender(
    "
function(el,x) {
  this.on('popupopen', function() {HTMLWidgets.staticRender();})
}
") %>%
  add_deps("highcharter") %>%
  browsable()
```

[image]

I have tried modified the 'popupopen' function without success.

Comment: Hi. Highcharts team is not able to help you with 3rd party libraries. I hope SO community will help you and if not, I suggest contacting Leaflet or Highcharter authors. Regards!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### First, the solution:

```
leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addCircleMarkers(lat = 45.4, lng = 14.9,
                   popup = list(paste(as.character(
                     hchart(data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10), type = "line", hcaes(x = x, y = y)) %>% hc_size(width = 300, height = 200)
                   ))),
                   popupOptions = popupOptions(minWidth = 300, maxHeight = 200)) %>%
  onRender(
    "
function(el,x) {
  this.on('popupopen', function() {HTMLWidgets.staticRender();})
}
") %>%
  add_deps("highchart", 'highcharter') %>%
  browsable()
```

[image]

#### And now, why?

This is due to the `add_deps` function:

```
add_deps <- function(dtbl, name, pkg = name) {
  tagList(
    dtbl,
    htmlwidgets::getDependency(name, pkg)
  )
}
```

As you can see, it uses internally `htmlwidgets::getDependency`. If we try with `leaflet` package:

```r
library(htmlwidgets)
getDependency('leaflet')[1:3]
#> [[1]]
#> List of 10
#>  $ name      : chr "htmlwidgets"
#>  $ version   : chr "1.5.1"
#>  $ src       :List of 1
#>   ..$ file: chr "/home/malditobarbudo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/htmlwidgets/www"
#>  $ meta      : NULL
#>  $ script    : chr "htmlwidgets.js"
#>  $ stylesheet: NULL
#>  $ head      : NULL
#>  $ attachment: NULL
#>  $ package   : NULL
#>  $ all_files : logi TRUE
#>  - attr(*, "class")= chr "html_dependency"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> List of 10
#>  $ name      : chr "jquery"
#>  $ version   : chr "1.12.4"
#>  $ src       :List of 1
#>   ..$ file: chr "/home/malditobarbudo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/leaflet/htmlwidgets/lib/jquery"
#>  $ meta      : NULL
#>  $ script    : chr "jquery.min.js"
#>  $ stylesheet: NULL
#>  $ head      : NULL
#>  $ attachment: NULL
#>  $ package   : NULL
#>  $ all_files : logi TRUE
#>  - attr(*, "class")= chr "html_dependency"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> List of 10
#>  $ name      : chr "leaflet"
#>  $ version   : chr "1.3.1"
#>  $ src       :List of 1
#>   ..$ file: chr "/home/malditobarbudo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/leaflet/htmlwidgets/lib/leaflet"
#>  $ meta      : NULL
#>  $ script    : chr "leaflet.js"
#>  $ stylesheet: chr "leaflet.css"
#>  $ head      : NULL
#>  $ attachment: NULL
#>  $ package   : NULL
#>  $ all_files : logi TRUE
#>  - attr(*, "class")= chr "html_dependency"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

we can see that it returns a list of `leaflet` js dependencies (truncated to the first three). If we try the same for `highcharter` it does not return any dependency (besides the mandatory htmlwidgets dependency)

```r
library(htmlwidgets)
getDependency('highcharter')
#> [[1]]
#> List of 10
#>  $ name      : chr "htmlwidgets"
#>  $ version   : chr "1.5.1"
#>  $ src       :List of 1
#>   ..$ file: chr "/home/malditobarbudo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/htmlwidgets/www"
#>  $ meta      : NULL
#>  $ script    : chr "htmlwidgets.js"
#>  $ stylesheet: NULL
#>  $ head      : NULL
#>  $ attachment: NULL
#>  $ package   : NULL
#>  $ all_files : logi TRUE
#>  - attr(*, "class")= chr "html_dependency"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> NULL
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

This is because `highcharter` is the R package name, not the js library name. You
can look at `list.files(system.file('htmlwidgets', package = 'highcharter'))` to
see that the library is called **highchart**, so using the correct name in this
bit:

```
{...} %>%
  add_deps("highchart", 'highcharter') %>%
  {...}
```

will do the trick ;)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much for a great explanation

Comment: Did someone tried to insert it in a shiny App?
I have tried the following and it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Pierre and @MalditoBarbudo, I have tried to adapt your exemple in a shinyApp and I was not able to run it corretly

Can I have some help please?

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(htmltools)
library(leaflet)
library(highcharter)

as.character.htmlwidget <- function(x, ...) {
  htmltools::HTML(
    htmltools:::as.character.shiny.tag.list(
      htmlwidgets:::as.tags.htmlwidget(
        x
      ),
      ...
    )
  )
}


add_deps <- function(dtbl, name, pkg = name) {
  tagList(
    dtbl,
    htmlwidgets::getDependency(name, pkg)
  )
}


ui = fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("map")
)

#server.r
server = function(input, output, session) {


  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% 
      addTiles() %>% 
      addCircleMarkers(lat = 45.4, lng = 14.9,
                       popup = list(paste(as.character(
                         hchart(data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10), type = "line", hcaes(x = x, y = y)) %>% hc_size(width = 300, height = 200)
                       ))),
                       popupOptions = popupOptions(minWidth = 300, maxHeight = 200)) %>%
      onRender(
        "
function(el,x) {
  this.on('popupopen', function() {HTMLWidgets.staticRender();})
}
") %>%
      add_deps("highchart", 'highcharter') %>%
      browsable()

    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```